# PHP type function parameter to check

Tags: php, types

how would it be possible to pass a type to a function, so it can check if an object is from the passed Type.

My attempt seems not to work:

```
class Test {
    function __construct() {

    }
}
function check(Type) {
    $x = new Test();
    if ($x instanceof Type) {
        print_r("the object is from the type of the passed variable! :)");
    }
}
check(Test);
```

Comment: Just pass the type name as a string.

Comment: See [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php). It won't work with inheritance, but it might suffice for your needs.

Comment: Or use  `is_a($object,$classname)` function from php http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

Comment: thx for the fast reply but no, I dont want to pass it as string. Isnt there something like the generic methods in Java / C#?

Comment: `not pass it as strint` As what then? , But lets combine `is_a($object,get_class($otherwhatver))` and if you are really coming from `C#` then, you will have a hard time with php ;-)

Comment: @marius Java doesn't allow you to pass a type either. You would pass `typeInstance.getClass()` or `Type.class` to pass a `Class` object. The PHP equivalent is just a string you can get from `get_class($typeInstance)` or `Type::class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to instantiate the type like you have done above you can pass the classname as a string.

```
function check($class_str)
{
    $x = new $class_str();
    if($x instanceof Test) {
        print_r("the object is from the type of the passed variable! :)");
    }
}
check('Test');
```

Comment: so it lookes like there is no work to directly ask for the type, only over string operations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correctely understand your question but if I'm right, here is how I did a list object than can store only one specific type or object :

```
class DList extends DVector {
/**
 * @param string $template The name of the type to store
 */
public function __construct($template){
    parent::__construct();
    if(!class_exists($template)){
        if(in_array($template, array(self::Bool, self::Integer, self::String, self::Float, self::Map))){
            $this->_template = $template;
            $this->_callback = '_isTemplateType';
        } else {
            throw new DListTemplateTypeException('Unable to find the class "' . $template. '" ');
        }
    } else {
        $this->_template = $template;
        $this->_callback = '_isTemplateInstance';
    }
}

private function _isTemplateType($value){
    return gettype($value) == $this->_template;
}

private function _isTemplateInstance($value){
    return $value instanceof $this->_template;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check($type) {
    $x = new Test();
    if (is_subclass_of($x, $type)) {
        print_r("the object is from the type of the passed variable! :)");
    }
}
check("Test");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php